# Unable to resolve raml file errors

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, raml

I have been given the attached RAML file to use in Mule but I am having problems working out how to clean up the errors in the file and not even sure this raml file conforms to standards.  The errors I am getting are for missing {} and another is missing block entry when I remove the version.   Can't figure out how to resolve them.

Below is a cut down version of the RAML:

```
#%RAML 0.8
---
title: Databox
version: v1
protocols: [HTTPS]
baseUri: https://databox/v1/{version}
mediaType: application/json
traits:
  - http-data: !include http-data.raml
resourceTypes: !include types.raml

documentation:
  - title: Home
    content: |
      Databox 1st draft

/stores:
  type:
    store:
      description: Stores
      dataSchema: !include stores.json
```

**The traits (http-data.raml):**

```
responses:
  200:
    description: |
      Success
```

**The resourceType (types.raml):**

```
- store:
    head:
      description: Retrieve data for <<description>>.
      is: [ http-data ]
    get:
      description: Retrieve data for <<description>>.
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              schema: |
               {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "meta": {
                    "title": "Data",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "createdOn": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "createdOn"
                    ]
                  },
                  "data": {
                   "type": "array",
                   "items": <<dataSchema>>
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "data"
                ]
               }
          description: |
            Success. Returns a JSON object containing all <<description>>.
```

**The schema (stores.json):**

```
{
  "id": "http://localhost:8000/stores.json#",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "Databox Store Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "storeId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storeDescription": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  },
  "required": [
    "storeId"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the exact errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

RAML is valid except for that `<<dataSchema>>` parameter used in the json schema, not sure if that's a valid use of parameters.

I would start by replacing that `<<dataSchema>>` for the json in stores.json and try again.

Let me know if that works or what errors you get.

UPDATE:

Mulesoft's anypoint portal validates your RAML with just that single change, you can see it [here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/541111111/#/portals/organizations/2110c4b3-e1a1-45bb-b6e8-5c540f46630d/apis/38026/versions/39692)

Comment: I have replaced it <<dataSchema>> with stores.json and I still have the error "expected <block end>, but found BlockEntry" highlighted on the 2nd line of the RAML file (----) in Mule

Comment: Remove the second line "---"

Comment: I've tried that but it just seems to move the error somewhere else.  I have noticed that if I remove the schema from the resourceType then all the errors go away.  I have retyped it and the errors come back when I try to add "required" and also "data" with the <<dataSchema>> reference.  Adding "required" looks valid so not sure why that would cause an error, not sure about dataSchema

Comment: Need to reuse that response and update it with different schemas  (<<dataSchema>>) depending on the call

Comment: Mulesoft's anypoint portal validates your RAML with just that single change, you can see it here: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/541111111/#/portals/organizations/2110c4b3-e1a1-45bb-b6e8-5c540f46630d/apis/38026/versions/39692

Comment: Thanks.  I've found that I can add <<dataSchema>> if I change "items" to "item" and that removes that error but for some reason I can't specify required fields